# Canada Transit Visa

Tags: canada, transit-visas, air-canada

Could someone please help me how to contact Canada Embassy regarding my transit visa? Its been more than 21 days since I applied for the transit visa for which I have not received any update yet.

Comment: Which Canadian embassy are you trying to contact?

Comment: I stay in Sacramento. So I am assuming I should be contacting the one in Los Angeles

Answer (score 1):

Canada has outsourced its visa processing in the US to VFS Global. You can [track your application](https://www.vfsglobal.ca/canada/usa/track-your-application.html) online through their web site.

There is also a helpline number on that page: +18882964511, along with their email address and a link to an online chat service.

Good luck!

Comment: So apparently they only help sending passports to the embassy and any paper applications.